# Missing vertices in procedurally generated mesh in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to procedurally generate a mesh made out of quads, but at the positive y and negative z edges half of the quad is not rendered at all. I can sort of see why it happens, but I don't know how to fix it.

```cs
    public void create(byte[,,] blocks) {
        for(int z = 0; z < 16; z++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                    if(x == 0) {
                        int CurrentCount = vertices.Count;
 
                        vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y + 1f, z + 1f));
                        vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y - 1f, z + 1f));
                        vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y - 1f, z - 1f));
                        vertices.Add(new Vector3(x, y + 1f, z - 1f));
 
                        indices.Add(CurrentCount);
                        indices.Add(CurrentCount + 1);
                        indices.Add(CurrentCount + 2);
 
                        indices.Add(CurrentCount + 2);
                        indices.Add(CurrentCount);
                        indices.Add(CurrentCount + 3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: what actually is your most inner loop for if you anyway only use the cases where `x==0` ...?

Comment: because right now i am just trying to get the quads to display correctly (which clearly doesn't work), before actually making use of the loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the normals.

- Triangle goes clockwise -> normal shows in your direction.

  [image]
- Triangle goes counter-clockwise -> normal shows away from you => Due to backface culling it is not rendered

  [image]

What you are doing is defining all your vertices in clockwise order like

```
(CurrentCount + 3)--------(CurrentCount + 0)
       |                         |
       |                         |
       |                         |
(CurrentCount + 2)--------(CurrentCount + 1)
```

and then create one triangle with indices in clockwise order

```
indices.Add(CurrentCount);
indices.Add(CurrentCount + 1);
indices.Add(CurrentCount + 2);
```

But the other one with counter-clockwise index order

```
indices.Add(CurrentCount + 2);
indices.Add(CurrentCount);
indices.Add(CurrentCount + 3);
```

You can see this quite good when you a) enter the wire-frame mode and be move to the other side of the plane

[image]

---

It should rather be

```
indices.Add(CurrentCount);
indices.Add(CurrentCount + 1);
indices.Add(CurrentCount + 2);

indices.Add(CurrentCount);
indices.Add(CurrentCount + 2);
indices.Add(CurrentCount + 3);
```

which now constructs one correct plane facing the "right" side of the Unity world

[image]